# Asp.net buttons event click without do postback. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, autopostback, onclientclick

I would like to know if is possible to use a `asp:button`, use an event click. and call a javascript instead code behind without to do postback?
I need to record voice and I´m using javascript to do this.
Someone could help me?

Comment: ... just use a <Button/>?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your button and use the OnClientClick Property in this way:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click me" OnClientClick="myFunction(); return false;" />
```

With that you call `myFunction();` and the `return false;` prevent the `__doPostBack` function will be called avoiding the postback.

Comment: It doesn´t work for me because these buttons are inside  usercontrol and when I click postback is fire automatically.

Comment: Could you post some code to get a better idea of the problem

Comment: <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <cc1:ImageButtonGravarAudio ID="ImageButtonGravarAudio1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/record1.png" OnClientClick="toggleRecording(this);  false" class=""/></td>
        <td>
            <a id="save" href="#">
            <img src="../Resources/play1.png"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

Comment: OnClientClick="toggleRecording(this); false" at the end must be `return false;` not just `false`

Comment: I´ve change and it´ doesn´t work. The problem I think is that This code is inside webusercontrol

Comment: The toogleRecording function may have the code to make the posbtack, if you have access to the user control check how the onclientclick property is set to the button